# On the function of dignus

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice

Usually, when we say *Marcus dignus amictiā* we mean that Marcus is entitled to or worthy of friendship. Keeping the direction but increasing volume we can say "Marcus (On account of his character) should have a friendship".

The question here asks if we can also understand the direction can be opposite with *dignus* i.e., friendship is entitled to have Marcus. Better example to illustrate the distinction: *Marcus dignus est Claudiā*.

The context of this question was [Matthew 3:8 translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=GaNCAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA9&lpg=RA1-PA9&dq=%22Edite%20ergo%20fructus%20emendata%22&source=bl&ots=IriBr4O1-M&sig=ACfU3U3q0o8KMREmq9mUs2MU2jKrn6Wz-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX1_3GlbKEAxX-7AIHHUdlCaYQ6AF6BAgXEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Edite%20ergo%20fructus%20emendata%22&f=false) by Sebastian Castellio that caught my attention:

> Edite ergo fructus emendatā vitā dignos

To my understanding the usage of the passive participle *emendata* pretty much forces the direction (perhaps deliberately trying to do it) : "Bring forth fruits that the corrected life is entitled to have"; and not the usual(?) usage of *dignus* "fruits entitled to have ..."

In the Vulgare we read (not sure why singular *fructus*):

> Facite ergo fructum dignum poenitentiae.

Can the Vulgate translation be understood in more than one way? Does Castellio's translation work in classical Latin?

---

The question is about the Latin of course. but it worth mentioning that per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_3:8) in the original Greek both readings are possible which was a source of dispute. So at least there is Greek formalization that enables both direction. Is the Jerome Latin also?

Comment: The Vulgate has a singular because the Greek has a singular (καρπὸν). I don't know why Castellio has a plural, but the KJV does as well.